# Null out list of columns' row values based on another column

Tags: list, powerquery

I have an example table below:

| first_name | last_name | country | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | UK | 100 | 200 | null | null |
| John | Doe | France | 150 | 50 | null | 100 |
| Mike | Lin | US | null | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| Anna | How | Germany | null | null | 50 | 90 |
| Anna | How | UK | 90 | 200 | 800 | null |

How can I null out the 2019 onward columns to null if the country is UK? The year columns will eventually grow, so I'm trying to adapt for that. The first three columns will not change.

Output:

| first_name | last_name | country | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | UK | null | null | null | null |
| John | Doe | France | 150 | 50 | null | 100 |
| Mike | Lin | US | null | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| Anna | How | Germany | null | null | 50 | 90 |
| Anna | How | UK | null | null | null | null |

I was thinking of having `List.RemoveItems()` to get a list of the year columns. I'm trying to go with `each if` when doing the conditionals and then using `Replacer.ReplaceValue` where the value is `>0` and replace with `null`, but not sure how to apply this to the list of columns.

Comment: David has the right answer, but why do this instead of just filtering out the entire row?

Comment: Agreed and it isn't a good layout for downstream analysis. Really, the year should be a single column if you want to do anything useful with this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This will account for new years too.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"first_name", type text}, {"last_name", type text}, {"country", type text}, {"2019", Int64.Type}, {"2020", Int64.Type}, {"2021", Int64.Type}, {"2022", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"first_name", "last_name", "country"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Custom", each if [country] = "UK" then null else [Value]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"first_name", Order.Ascending}, {"last_name", Order.Ascending}, {"Attribute", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Custom")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```